# How can I get the Visual Studio 2010 converstion wizard to come back up?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wizard

When I first opened my website project with Visual Studio 2010 the conversion wizard
came up and I said that I didn't want to convert the project.

Now I'm ready to convert the project, but I can't find a shortcut or a way to get it back?  I tried to remove the suo file, and that didn't do it.

If I go into the project properties I can switch the target framework to 4.0, but that tells me it's going to close and reopen the project and I'll have to adjust the pages by hand - doesn't seem like very much fun.

Anyone know how to get it to prompt again, or even a command line that would run it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I can do it manually, I'm not sure the wizard can be run again.  I found the command line to run the wizard, but I think that's just an upgrade to VS2010.

Here's how to upgrade from 3.5 to 4.0, fwiw:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx